# SVD on symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following argument: let $C ∈ \mathbb R^{n×n}$ be such that $C^TC = CC^T$ . Using the SVD we can write $C = UΣV^T$ , and since $C^TC = CC^T$ we
see that $VΣ^TU^TUΣV^T = UΣV^TVΣU^T$ and thus $VΣ^TΣV^T = UΣΣ^TU^T$ .
Therefore $U = V$ and $C$ is a symmetric matrix. Can you say something on
the soundness of this argument with appropriate justifications?

Comment: Using svd is overkill. $(AB)^T =B^T A^T$